# getting HTML source of the web page using c# for different browsers

Tags: c#, html

I want to get the HTML source of the web page using c#, as if it was visited using different browsers like IE9, Chrome, Firefox. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The HTML comes from a web SERVER which delivers the same HTML to ALL BROWSERS (there are exceptions, but generally this is true). That's the whole point of HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the HTML source in a number of ways.  My preferred method is [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("http://domain.com/resource/page.html");
doc.Save("file.htm");
```

The [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) in .NET works well too.

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
myWebClient.Headers.Add ("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)"); // If you need to simulate a specific browser
byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData (remoteUri);
string download = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
// This is verbatim from MSDN... unfortunately their example does not dispose
// of myWebClient (it implements IDisposable).  You should wrap use of a WebClient
// in a using statement.
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx

The HTML you get is what you get.  A given browser decides what to make of it (unless, that is, the server renders different HTML for different user agents).

If you do need to explicitly set the user agent (to simulate different browsers), the following post shows how to do that:

http://blog.abodit.com/2010/03/a-simple-web-crawler-in-c-using-htmlagilitypack/

(this link also implements a simple web crawler using HTML Agility Pack)

Comment: I love it!  Makes life sooo easy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no C# expert, but assuming the html will be the same regardless of which "browser" visits the url, you can use System.Net.WebClient (if you only need simple control) or HttpWebRequest (if you need more advanced control)

For WebClient, just create an instance and call one of it's Download* methods:

```
var cli = new WebClient();
string data = cli.DownloadString("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Comment: Some websites use user agent sniffing to sometimes cater to the browser reading their site.  Especially if you set your user agent to IE4 (yes, old), some ASP.NET user controls will render differently, and this is done automatically without the websites author direct intervention.  Other sites might do a redirect to a mobile site if the useragent contains the words iPhone or Android