# c# copy Chrome webpage content

Tags: c#, string, windows, forms, google-chrome

Hi all I have this problem.

I need to open a webpage in chrome and copy the content (the page displays only 1 line of text, no images or anything)

Page source would be ok(it's the same thing).

My c# software is able to generate that link and to open it in chrome (it's important not to use webforms or IE)

But then I would need to "get" the text displayed by chrome and use it in my software again.

I hope it's clear:

my sofwtare generates a link containing needed text--->open link in chrome-->get text content or page source--->elaborate it inside my c# sofware again (maybe copy it to a string or so)

I'm a newbie. Sorry guys.

Comment: So you cannot use RESTful services?

Comment: @Igoranze RESTful service for what ?

Comment: is it mandatory to open link in chrome and get the page content ? or any other way can be possible ?

Comment: RESTful to get the content of <body></body> and post it to your application with JSON or something?

Comment: @MostafizurRahman 
in chrome it also open with URL or what ?

Comment: didn't get your comment what do you want to say @PranavPatel ?

Comment: he said from chrome, but in the end in chrome too it will opened by url only, as he said `My c# software is able to generate that link and to open it in chrome` so why not to use that `link` only @MostafizurRahman

Comment: then there is lot of way to get data from url without chrome like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255554/getting-html-source-of-the-web-page-using-c-sharp-for-different-browsers

Comment: Guys here is the situation. I need to get this content from my website where I'm logged in (user and pass) .This is why it cannot be made with IE or webforms. It simply won't work. 
I calculate the right link on c# and then launch chrome. It shows a code I need to import back to my c# software